# PHP Adding array values together

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays, json

I have an array in the format of

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [platform] => 1
            [sales] => 244
            [total] => 245971.00
            [average] => 1008.08
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [platform] => 2
            [sales] => 273
            [total] => 280454.48
            [average] => 1027.31
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [platform] => 3
            [sales] => 290
            [total] => 273408.00
            [average] => 942.79
        )

)
```

and another array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [platform] => 1
            [sales] => 243
            [total] => 245231.00
            [average] => 1128.08
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [platform] => 2
            [sales] => 233
            [total] => 2804248
            [average] => 103.31
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [platform] => 3
            [sales] => 293
            [total] => 223408.00
            [average] => 942.29
        )

)
```

How could I add these arrays together to create an array of all the values added.

For example, `[sales] => 244` from the first array containing platform 11 and `[sales] => 243` in the seconds array containing platform 1. I want to combine them into an array where `[sales] => 487` (244 + 243) for platform 1.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may need adding operator(`+`). Also something to loop the array, like `foreach`.

Comment: Yes but my problem is I can't just be going `$arrayC = $arrayA + $arrayB`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the two arrays have an exact 1:1 match between their respective keys:

```
$new_arr = array();
foreach($arr1 as $main_key => $sub_arr) {
    foreach($sub_arr as $sub_key => $val) {
        $new_arr[$main_key][$sub_key] = $val + $arr2[$main_key][$sub_key];
    }
}
```

where $arr1 and $arr2 are your two original arrays.

Comment: Ah, I have the issue of the platform numbers being added together also, but now I come to think of it, maybe the platform numbers shouldn't even be there.

Answer (score -1):

You can also merge two arrays by array_merge
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: Array_merge does not add numerical values, it appends or overwrites values.